# jQuery Mobile Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a working external panel but am having some issues. Here's the HTML:

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>My Page</title> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        /* add panel */
            $( document ).on( "mobileinit" , function() {
                var panel = '<div>panel</div>';
                $( "body" ).prepend( panel ); /* or .append */
            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        /* initialize panel and contents */
            $(function() {
                $( "[data-role=panel]" ).panel().enhanceWithin(); /* or #panelID or .class */
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div data-role="panel" class="panel left panel-01" data-position="left" data-display="push" id="panel-01">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
              <li><a href="#profile">My Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Recent Activities</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">FAQ </a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Terms and Use</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Full Site</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="home" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="header"> <a href="#panel-01" class="menuIcon ico fl">menu</a>

                 <h1>Home</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="content">content
                <div data-role="listview" style="margin:1em; border-radius:10px;">
                    <ul data-role="listview" style="margin:1em; border-radius:10px;">
                        <li><a href="#about">About us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="about" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="header"> <a href="#panel-01" class="menuIcon ico fl">menu</a>

                 <h1>About us</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="content">About us
                <div data-role="listview" style="margin:1em; border-radius:10px;">
                    <ul data-role="listview" style="margin:1em; border-radius:10px;">
                        <li><a href="#home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <!--<h4>Footer</h4>-->footer</div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="profile" data-position="fixed">
            <div data-role="header"> <a href="#panel-01" class="menuIcon ico fl">menu</a>

                 <h1>My Profile</h1>

            </div>
            <div data-role="content" class="content">About us
                <div data-role="listview" style="margin:1em; border-radius:10px;">
                    <ul data-role="listview" style="margin:1em; border-radius:10px;">
                        <li><a href="#home">Profiles</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm testing this in Chrome and I'm getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The code was taken from different sources but seems to be a typical example of loading an external panel.

**How do I correct the "undefined function" error?**

Answer (score 1):

You have to include jQuery mobile before `on()`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
/* add panel */
$( document ).on( "mobileinit" , function() {
var panel = '<div>panel</div>';
$( "body" ).prepend( panel ); /* or .append */
});
</script>
```

Comment: The error isn't on the first script, it 's on the second:     $(function() { $( "[data-role=panel]" ).panel().enhanceWithin();...